# py2neo.database.ClientError: SemanticError: Cannot merge node using null property value for Country

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to merge the query below to an existing database in Neo4j. I already have a neo4j graph created using the following parameters, which are working fine. This was created using neo4j application.

```
Name, Entity, Web_Site, Title, Other-names, Active, up, down (8 properties)
```

I am trying to merge the above-created graph with the query below using python. I am adding extra properties with the below query to the already existing database. When I run the query below it gives me this error:

```
py2neo.database.ClientError: SemanticError: Cannot merge node using null property value for Country.
```

How do I make it skip every row or column with null values using the python query?

```
query = """
           merge(name:name {name: {a},name:{b},Title:{c}, 
                 status:{d},number:{e},Code:{f},Country:{g},Locality:{h},Address:{i}})

                """
    batch.run(query,{"a": name, "b": Type, "c":Title, "d": status, "e":number, "f":Code,
                    "g": Country,"h": Locality,"i":Address})
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient (and simplest) approach would be to simply modify your Python code to avoid making the neo4j query if any of the [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) values would be `null`.

Comment: I have been trying to do that, but it keeps throwing up the same error. I tried the syntax i saw here https://community.neo4j.com/t/load-csv-with-empty-cells/5091/4,it works for a single line and stops.